# Passing function variable to another one in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two functions in jQuery.

```
       var resume = 'Res';

          resumeUpload.onchange = function() {

          var resume = $('#fileup2')[0].files[0];

          var imageName = $('#fileup2')[0].files[0].name;

          $('.resume').append(`<li><span class="remove-file remove-resume btn f-20 mr-2">X</span>&nbsp;<span>${imageName}</span></li>`);

        }

        $(document).on('click','.remove-resume',function(){

          $('.resume').html('');

          var resume = '';

        });
        $('.applyTeacher').on('click', function () {
          console.log(resume)
         }
```

The first variable resume gets the file on change and I am passing it in the third function but console comes empty instead of showing the file as it is not passing there. Can anyone please help?

P.S. : I only get Res in console and not the file.

Comment: `var resume` means it's only defined inside the individual functions. You probably want to declare `var resume;` outside of these functions.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have already declared that outside of these functions and it is not working. I mean it is picking the global variable and not the variable mentioned in the first function.

Answer (score 1):

I did it, by removing var from inside the functions.

```
var resume = 'Res';

      resumeUpload.onchange = function() {

      resume = $('#fileup2')[0].files[0];

      var imageName = $('#fileup2')[0].files[0].name;

      $('.resume').append(`<li><span class="remove-file remove-resume btn f-20 mr-2">X</span>&nbsp;<span>${imageName}</span></li>`);

    }

    $(document).on('click','.remove-resume',function(){

      $('.resume').html('');

      resume = '';

    });
    $('.applyTeacher').on('click', function () {
      console.log(resume)
     }
```